# leaflet-shiny with country geojson layer

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I'm using R + Shiny to display a leaflet map. I would like to add several countries (in the form of layers) to this map and I have looked around and found this websites which offer the GEOJSON data:

[country GEOJSON data (detailed)](https://github.com/mledoze/countries)

[country GEOJSON data (simple)](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json)

My issue is that the coordinates in those files are longitude, latitude (following specifications). However, Leaflet (or Leaflet-Shiny) expects latitude, longitude for whatever reason.

What is the simplest way to swap the order?

Thanks.

Carlos

Comment: It seems there was not a problem after all ... I just added some styling to my layer and it displayed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest working example:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ShinyDash)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  gridster(tile.width = 125, tile.height = 125,
           gridsterItem(col = 1, row = 1, size.x = 4, size.y = 2,
                        leafletMap(
                          "map", "100%", "100%",
                          initialTileLayer = "http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                          initialTileLayerAttribution = HTML('Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>'),
                          options=list(
                            center = c(49.25, 16),
                            zoom = 2,
                            maxBounds = list(list(17, -180),
                                             list(59, 180))
                          )
                        )
           )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(RJSONIO)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
     # create leaflet map   map <- createLeafletMap(session, 'map')
     # Draw GeoJSON   m <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("./www/countries/esp.geo.json")
     m$style <- list(weight = 5, stroke = "true",
                  fill = "true", opacity = 1,
                  fillOpacity = 0.4)
     session$onFlushed(once=TRUE, function() {
    map$addMarker(ncoords[[1]][1], ncoords[[1]][2])
    map$addGeoJSON(m)   }) })
```